# Mounting Drive with Specific Name in Mac with hdiutil

Tags: macos, command, mount

I am installing some apps with shell module in ansible. i want to write scripts which is generic for different versions.

```
- name: Installing Sublime Text
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
  - hdiutil mount "{{download_location}}/sublime.dmg"
  - cp -R /Volumes/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app "{{applications_location}}/Sublime Text.app"
  - hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

Right now i am using attach/mount, but the problem is when i install multiple versions, each have its own folder structure with different name, i have to create scripts seperately to copy for that.

```
hdiutil mount --name common
cp -R /Volumes/common/myapp.app destination
```

if i get the folder name common i can copy common/*app to destination. 
**How can i mount the dmg file with specific name?**

Comment: Re: "each have its own folder structure with different name", meaning the `.dmg` has a different name or the directory structure on it has a different name? Show two examples so we know what you are looking at.

Comment: different names and also different folder structure. eg:`/Volumes/Sublime Text 2/Sublime Text 2.app` and `/Volumes/Sublime Text/Sublime Text.app`

Comment: Is `destination` the attached/mounted volume, and why in the first example do you use `mount`, and the second one you use `attach`?

Comment: attach and mount gives me the same functionality. destination is some other folder. source is the apps which resides inside the mounted folder.

Answer (score 1):

### hdiutil attach/mount

Here's a fairly simple way of attaching/mounting a `.dmg` that I was able to come up with:

```
var=$(ls | egrep -m1 ".*Sub.*dmg"); yes y | hdiutil attach $var
```

The command tries to locate and mount anything that contains "Sub" in the name which is a `.dmg`. Using `yes y` accepts an agreement notice if one is presented. If you don't think you'll encounter anything like that you can always remove it.

### cp to destination:

```
cp -R /Volumes/*Sub*/*.app ~/Path/To/Destination
```

The next command searches for any mounted or attached volumes containing the word "Sub" as the volume name; the .app is then copied to the destination. If you have multiple `.dmg` files you want to mount/attach and copy the files to a destination a recursive `find` can be used:

### recursive hdiutil/mount + cp

```
yes y | find . -regex ".*Sub.*dmg" -exec hdiutil attach {} \;
find /Volumes/*Sub*/* -regex ".*\.app" -exec cp -R {} ~/Path/To/Destination \;
```

This should find *any* .dmgs containing "Sub", mount them *all* and copy the `.app` from each volume to the destination. ***Use with caution*** — it will copy over files that are of the same name in the destination without warning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mount at a particular destination with the following command.

```
hdiutil mount common.dmg -mountpoint "/Volumes/common"
```

Then, you can copy the .app to the destination.

```
cp -R "/Volumes/common/common.app" "/Applications/"
```

Then, you can detach it using following command.

```
hdiutil detach "/Volumes/common"
```